# Swift app crashes only when archived (exported). NSLog related

Tags: swift, macos

I have a macOS app in swift that **crashes only when archived** (not run from XCode).

It crashes on the following code:

```
private static func myFunc(originalValue: String) {
    DLog("Starting myFunc on: '\(originalValue)'") // CRASHES when app is exported
}
```

Here is the DLog function (when exported, the DEBUG flag is not set, so it will not execute the NSLog):

```
func DLog(_ message: String, function: String = #function) {
    #if DEBUG
        NSLog("%@, %@", function, message)
    #endif
}
```

The `originalValue` that makes the app crash is a String containing basic characters (letters or numbers), no `%@` or other format string stuff.

Now the funniest part, if I print (using Swift.print) `originalValue` before calling `DLog`, it won't crash:

```
private static func myFunc(originalValue: String) {
    print("Starting myFunc on: '\(originalValue)'") // prevents the crash
    DLog("Starting myFunc on: '\(originalValue)'") // DOES NOT crash because of the print before
}
```

Any logical explanation to this strange behavior?

Thanks!